# Drawing in an other window

Tags: java

I am trying to realize a button that activates lines drawing in an other window.

I vave 3 classes:

Table_Workspace - extends JFrame class contains the button;

Table_graph - extends JFrame class. It contains, besides other, an element of type ActiveZone

ActiveZone - extends JPanel class which overrides paintComponent  function:

================================================================================

```
public class ActiveZone extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(1, 1, 20, 20);
        System.out.print("Add img");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Table_Workspace extends JFrame {
//.....
btnBuild = new JButton("Build");
contentPane.add(btnBuild);
btnBuild.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ActiveZone activezone = new ActiveZone();
                Table_graph table_graph = new Table_graph(); //window in which we draw
                //sl_contentPane = SpringLayout() from Table_graph
                table_graph.sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,
                        activezone, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH,
                        table_graph.GridPanel);
                table_graph.sl_contentPane
                        .putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, activezone, 0,
                                SpringLayout.EAST, table_graph.GridPanel);
                table_graph.sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,
                        activezone, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH,
                        table_graph.GridPanel);
                table_graph.sl_contentPane
                        .putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, activezone, 0,
                                SpringLayout.WEST, table_graph.GridPanel);

                table_graph.contentPane.add(activezone, 0);
                table_graph.contentPane.revalidate();
                table_graph.contentPane.repaint();
                activezone.setOpaque(false);


            }
        });
```

================================================================================

During execution it outputs nothing, no in System.out, neither any error message.

But if I take the component creation code from Table_Workspace and
 put it to Table_graph everything works OK and the line is beeng drawn.
Like this:

=================================================================================

```
activezone = new ActiveZone();

sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, activezone, 0,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, GridPanel);
sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, activezone, 0,
                SpringLayout.EAST, GridPanel);
sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, activezone, 0,
                SpringLayout.SOUTH, GridPanel);
sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, activezone, 0,
                SpringLayout.WEST, GridPanel);
contentPane.add(activezone, 0);
activezone.setOpaque(false);
```

==================================================================================

Suggest me, please, whats wrong and how can I realize the idea?

Thank you in advance beforehand!